# MediaElement and fancybox no control buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2, mediaelement.js

Here is my homepage:

[jobrangers](http://jobrangers.com/newtemplate/flatone-default/)

Here is my code:

```
            // Detecting IE more effectively : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537509.aspx
        function getInternetExplorerVersion() {
            // Returns the version of Internet Explorer or -1 (other browser)
            var rv = -1; // Return value assumes failure.
            if (navigator.appName == 'Microsoft Internet Explorer') {
                var ua = navigator.userAgent;
                var re = new RegExp("MSIE ([0-9]{1,}[\.0-9]{0,})");
                if (re.exec(ua) != null)
                    rv = parseFloat(RegExp.$1);
            };
            return rv;
        };

        // set some general variables
        var $video_player, _videoHref, _videoPoster, _videoWidth, _videoHeight, _dataCaption, _player, _isPlaying = false, _verIE = getInternetExplorerVersion();
        jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {  
            jQuery(".fancy_video")
            .fancybox({
                // set type of content (remember, we are building the HTML5 <video> tag as content)
                type       : "html",
                // other API options
                scrolling  : "no",
                padding    : 0,
                nextEffect : "fade",
                prevEffect : "fade",
                nextSpeed  : 0,
                prevSpeed  : 0,
                fitToView  : false,
                autoSize   : false,
                modal      : true, // hide default close and navigation buttons
                helpers    : {
                    title  : {
                        type : "over"
                    },
                    buttons: {} // use buttons helpers so navigation button won't overlap video controls
                },
                beforeLoad : function () {
                    // if video is playing and we navigate to next/prev element of a fancyBox gallery
                    // safely remove Flash objects in IE
                    if (_isPlaying && (_verIE > -1)) {
                        // video is playing AND we are using IE
                        _verIE < 9.0 ? _player.remove() : $video_player.remove(); // remove player instance for IE
                        _isPlaying = false; // reinitialize flag
                    };
                    // build the HTML5 video structure for fancyBox content with specific parameters
                    _videoHref   = 'http://jobrangers.com/JobrangersHD.mp4';
                    // validates if data values were passed otherwise set defaults
                    _videoPoster = typeof this.element.data("poster")  !== "undefined" ? this.element.data("poster")  :  "";
                    _videoWidth  = typeof this.element.data("width")   !== "undefined" ? this.element.data("width")   : 360;
                    _videoHeight = typeof this.element.data("height")  !== "undefined" ? this.element.data("height")  : 360;
                    _dataCaption = typeof this.element.data("caption") !== "undefined" ? this.element.data("caption") :  "";
                    // construct fancyBox title (optional)
                    this.title = _dataCaption ? _dataCaption : (this.title ? this.title : "");
                    // set fancyBox content and pass parameters
                    this.content = "<video id='video_player' src='" + _videoHref + "'  poster='" + _videoPoster + "' width='" + _videoWidth + "' height='" + _videoHeight + "'  controls='controls' preload='none' ></video>";
                    // set fancyBox dimensions
                    this.width = _videoWidth;
                    this.height = _videoHeight;
                },
                afterShow : function () {
                    // initialize MEJS player
                    var $video_player = new MediaElementPlayer('#video_player', {
                            defaultVideoWidth : this.width,
                            defaultVideoHeight : this.height,
                            success : function (mediaElement, domObject) {
                                _player = mediaElement; // override the "mediaElement" instance to be used outside the success setting
                                _player.load(); // fixes webkit firing any method before player is ready
                                _player.play(); // autoplay video (optional)
                                _player.addEventListener('playing', function () {
                                    _isPlaying = true;
                                }, false);
                            } // success
                        });
                },
                beforeClose : function () {
                    // if video is playing and we close fancyBox
                    // safely remove Flash objects in IE
                    if (_isPlaying && (_verIE > -1)) {
                        // video is playing AND we are using IE
                        _verIE < 9.0 ? _player.remove() : $video_player.remove(); // remove player instance for IE
                        _isPlaying = false; // reinitialize flag
                    };
                }
            }); 
        }); // ready
```

For some reason, the controls are not showing up on my implementation. I copied the implementation from : [here](http://www.picssel.com/demos/play_videos_with_mediaelement_in_fancybox.html)

I think it might have to do with the opacity of the controls element?

Any help would be GREATLY APPRECIATED.

Answer (score 0):

You included your fancybox buttons css file like this

```
<link type="text/css" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/2.1.5/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.css" media="screen"/>
```

... but you missed the `rel="stylesheet"` attribute, which is required, otherwise regardess the link is included in your page the stylesheet won't load so :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/2.1.5/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.css" media="screen"/>
```

**EDIT**:

I also noticed you have this css rule :

```
http://jobrangers.com/newtemplate/flatone-default/css/style.css
Line 173
.top {
  background-color: rgba(0, 50, 73, 0.7);
  height: 600px;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

That conflicts with the fancybox buttons' rule

```
#fancybox-buttons.top {
  top: 10px;
}
```

in this case, the fancybox buttons inherits the `height: 600px;` css property because it shares the class `.top` hence it overlaps the video below, making its controls inaccessible.

You may need to set an extra css declaration **after** you load the fancybox buttons css file to fix that:

```
#fancybox-buttons.top {
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
  height: 32px;
  top: 10px;
}
```

Also **notice** when you enable `modal: true`, the `escape` button as well as the default `close` and `navigation` buttons are disabled. Check the fancybox [documentation](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#docs) for further reference.

Comment: How come there isnt an exit button or the escape button working?